# Incorrect answer given by Sum

Tags: summation

Is this a bug?

```
Sum[Binomial[2 n - 1, 2 m - 1]*(L - 2 - 2*(2 m - 1)), {m, 1, n}]
```

gives

```
-4^(-1 + n) (1 - L + 2 n)
```

However, clearly, if n=1, the series is `L-4` where m can take the only value of 1.

But the answer computed by Mathematica `-4^(-1 + n) (1 - L + 2 n)` with `n=1` simplifies to `L-3`?

I am using **MMA 14.0** on Windows.

Comment: Adding `GenerateConditions -> True` gives the same thing along with `n >= 1` which is a bug, but when you dont add that option i wouldn't say a return that works for `n > 1` is a bug.

Comment: `Sum` and `Integrate` often give results that whose dependence on parameters is only "generically true" (finite number of exceptions when the parameter is a positive integer). Might always want to check the first couple of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in pointing out that the result produced by Mathematica is only correct for `n>1`. This seems to comes from the term `Sum[Binomial[2 n - 1, 2 m - 1](2 m - 1)), {m, 1, n}]`. One can evaluate this by writing out the binomial expansions of the derivatives of `(1 + x)^(2n - 1)` and `(1 - x)^(2n - 1)`, and evaluating the difference at `x = 1`. The issue arises from the second term which has derivative `-(2n - 1)(1 - x)^(2n - 2)`. The Mathematica result assumes `n != 1` and sets this term to `0`. However, in the case `n = 1`, `(1 - x)^(2n - 1) = 1 - x`, which has derivative `-1`. For `n != 1`, say `n = 2`, `(1 - x)^(2n - 1) = 1-3x+3x^2-x^3`, the derivative is `-3 + 6x - 3x^2` for which the value is `0` at `x = 1` and this result holds for all `n > 1`.

If you enter `Sum[Binomial[2 n - 1, 2 m - 1]*(L - 2 - 2*(2 m - 1)), {m, 1, n},  Assumptions -> n == 1]`, Mathematica does produce `L - 4`, but not for assumptions such as `n >= 1`, where the answer you provided is the result.

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

sum1[n_Integer?Positive] := 
 Sum[Binomial[2  n - 1, 2  m - 1]*(L - 2 - 2*(2  m - 1)), {m, 1, n}]

sum1[1]

(* -4 + L *)
```

Generating a sequence,

```
seq = sum1 /@ Range[8] // Simplify

(* {-4 + L, 4 (-5 + L), 16 (-7 + L), 64 (-9 + L), 256 (-11 + L), 1024 (-13 + L), 
 4096 (-15 + L), 16384 (-17 + L)} *)
```

Using [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html)

```
sum2[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n]
```

[image]

The result is a [`DifferenceRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot.html)

```
sum2[n] // InputForm

(* DifferenceRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, 
   {16*\[FormalY][\[FormalN]] - 8*\[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] + 
      \[FormalY][2 + \[FormalN]] == 0, \[FormalY][1] == -4 + L, 
    \[FormalY][2] == 4*(-5 + L), \[FormalY][3] == 
     16*(-7 + L), \[FormalY][4] == 64*(-9 + L), 
    \[FormalY][5] == 256*(-11 + L), 
    \[FormalY][6] == 1024*(-13 + L), 
    \[FormalY][7] == 4096*(-15 + L)}]][n] *)
```

Verifying that the `DifferenceRoot` works beyond the original sequence:

```
And @@ (Table[sum1[n] == sum2[n], {n, 1, 50}] // Simplify)

(* True *)
```